# What is the good API for Creating Word Documents in Android?

Tags: android, ms-word, ms-office

There is a necessity to create word documents in my android application I have tried many library but all the libraries where suitable for java and very difficult to implement in android, please can you suggest any library for android (if any).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Aspose.Words for Android:  http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component.aspx
Very simple to implement and the good thing is that codes samples are also present in the documentation section. I am sure it can help you out!